# XPath filtering option (percentual)

Tags: wordpress, xpath, expression, filtering

I want to import some data from a `CSV` file to my `Wordpress`, and I am using XPath expression to filter the data.

My file has 2 columns. `miles_jan` and `miles_feb`. I want to only import records where the `miles_feb is 50% of miles_jan`.

I tried `/node[miles_feb = "0.5*miles_jan"]` but I don't think I did it right because the filtering did not work.

Comment: I just thought of something. Would it work if I used `/node[(miles_feb div miles_jan) <= 0,5]`

Comment: `//node[miles_feb > 0.5*miles_jan]`

Comment: Thanks @splash58 , I'll have to give that a try when I get home